# How many kings is it possible to have on the board at once?

Tags: checkers

Keeping in mind the force capture rule, how many kings is possible to have (of one colour) on the board at once in Checkers? What is the sequence leading up to this?

Comment: Are the answers not "2" and "any sequence legally possible in chess"?

Comment: @hexparrot: *Chequers*, not chess.

Comment: Haha teach me to be so reckless! Was reading chess puzzles for an hour and then saw this. Embarrassing oversight, my apologies!

Comment: I guess it also depends on what rules of Checkers you are playing. There are many variations with 8x8 boards, 10x10 boards, flying kings, men (not) being able to capture backwards. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts . What variation are you talking about?

Comment: @Ivo 8x8 board, men, king promotion, king is just a man but can move backwards.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about game state trivia and not actually playing the game.

Comment: @ColinD I don't see why that makes it off topic. We have rather a lot of questions about games that are not also about _playing_ the game.

Comment: @doppelgreener its all about 'usefulness'. I do not think an answer to this question will ever impact a real game of checkers.

Comment: @Colin This is Board and Card Games, I had a question about a board game, I didn't see another appropriate site on the network, I researched it and couldn't find it, can someone please answer?

Comment: @warspyking it could just be that nobody's answered because nobody who's yet seen the question _knows_ the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [**American checkers**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_draughts) on an 8x8 board, it is possible to get 24 kings on the board from the initial position. Here is a Java applet with a [**proof game of 211 moves**](http://icheckers.net/h4ns/games/ex_24kings.html).

For [**International draughts**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_draughts) on a 10x10 board, it is possible to get 40 kings on the board from the initial position. Here is a Java applet with a [**proof game of 389 moves**](http://10x10.dse.nl/problems/40kings.html).

Answer (score 3):

If your opponent is remarkably cooperative, you could, theoretically, get 12 kings on the board for your color.

Your opponent needs to open paths for you to get their back row in such a manner that you either do not get captured or can capture him on the way in.

I've had as many 8 in a game a couple times playing against a very not good opponent.

Comment: What's the move sequence for 12 kings then? Please edit that in your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @warspyking - not sure off the top of my head, and no checker board handy to play both sides to get the optimal turnout